# REACT-NATİVE - jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Tags: react-native

I try to generate android apk for react-native project. However it gives me this error. How can I solve this ?

> ```
> Execution failed for task ':app:packageReleaseBundle'.
> > java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: jarsigner.exefailed with exit code 1 :
>   jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
> ```

*I changed somethigs and now I am getting this error :*

> 1 exception was raised by workers:   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: jarsigner.exefailed with exit code 1 :
>   jarsigner: key associated with my-key-alias not a private key

Comment: none knows this issue ?

Answer (score 4):

I deleted android/.gradle folder and run the command ./gradlew bundleRelease again. it works for me.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you changed your upload keystore, so before building the bundle launch `./gradlew clean` from android project app.